# How to center a text inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have a javascript code that generates html to build a bar with css, but I need to center a text in the middle of the bar, this is my code:

```
                render: function(data, type, row, meta){
                    coord_str = data;
                    return $("<div></div>", {
                        "class": "bar-chart-bar"
                    }).append(function(){
                        var bars = [];
            color = 'blue';                         
                        }                           
                            bars.push($("<div></div>",{
                                "class": "bar " + "bar1"
                            }).css({
                                "background-color": color,
                                "width": coord_str + "%"
                            }))
                        return bars;
                    },"50%").prop("outerHTML")
                }
```

I would like the text "50%" in the "disk" column to be centered on the bar graph

[image: a busy cat]

Can someone help me? It seems something elementary of css but I do not give with the error.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `text-align:center` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Very easy with Flexbox :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height : 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border : green solid 2px;
}

div:before{
  content: "";
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width : 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

span{
   z-index : 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Centered text!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ready.

```
.bar-text {
    z-index-1; 
    position: absolute;  
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```